# How to export jsfiddle css part (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle

I am new to JavaScript, nevertheless JsFiddle.

Me and a very kind sir programmed this code via JSfiddle.
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/04nxp66s/13/) is a link to all of the code

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

var height = window.innerHeight;
var width = window.innerWidth;

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

var letter = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];

var currentLetters = [];

var px = height / 20;
var y = [];
var x = [];
var speed;
var acceleration;
var score;
var newIntervalKey = 0;
var letternumber = 0;
var score = 0;

// This part will detect the clicks of your buttons. It's the preferred method for
// handling events in JS as opposed to using the onClick attribute of HTML elements.

var startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');
startButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
 start();
}, false);

var stopButton = document.getElementById('stopButton');
stopButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
 stop();
}, false);

// This will get the key code of the keyboard key that the user pressed.
// Each letter corresponds to such a code, so that's how you can check
// if the user pressed the correct key. Obviously you will need to have
// some soft of a map of codes to letters.
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {

  // Getting a letter from a code. We have a function that does that.
  var currentlyPressedKey = getKeyFromCode(e.keyCode);
  
  // If the user pressed one of the letters currently in play, we
  // remove it from our currentLetters array. We are using a bad
  // way of doing it (using a for loop) because I don't know if
  // you have covered array methods yet.
  for (var i = 0; i < currentLetters.length; i++) {
   var letterObj = currentLetters[i];
    if (letterObj.l == currentlyPressedKey) {
     currentLetters.splice(i, 1);
      score += 1;
    }
  }
}, false);

function getKeyFromCode(code) {
 switch (code) {
   case 65:
     return 'A';
    case 66:
     return 'B';
    case 67:
     return 'C';
    case 68:
     return 'D';
    case 69:
     return 'E';
    case 70:
     return 'F';
    case 71:
     return 'G';
    case 72:
     return 'H';
    case 73:
     return 'I';
    case 74:
     return 'J';
    case 75:
     return 'K';
    case 76:
     return 'L'
    case 77:
     return 'M';
    case 78:
     return 'N';
    case 79:
     return 'O';
    case 80:
     return 'P';
    case 81:
     return 'Q';
    case 82:
     return 'R';
    case 83:
     return 'S'
    case 84:
     return 'T';
    case 85:
     return 'U';
    case 86:
     return 'V';
    case 87:
     return 'W'
    case 88:
     return 'X';
    case 89:
     return 'Y';
    case 90:
     return 'Z';
    //case 50:
    // return 'W';
    
    default:
     return null;
  }
}

function addRandomLetter() {
 var letternumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26);
  
  // This will pick the x and y coordinated for each letter. It will need to be
  // updated later, because right now it's technically possible to place a
  // letter all the way on the bottom or on the right, where the user won't be
  // able to see it.
  var positionX = Math.floor(Math.random() * width);
  var positionY = Math.floor(Math.random() * height);
  
  // This saves an object to our array of current letters. The object contains
  // the letter itself, but also its x and y coordinates that we generated above.
 currentLetters.push({l: letter[letternumber], x: positionX, y: positionY});
}

function start() {

 c.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
 letternumber = 0;
  currentLetters = []
  score = 0;
  
 if(newIntervalKey != 0) {
  clearInterval(newIntervalKey)
 }
  
 newIntervalKey = setInterval(where, 1000);
}

function stop() {
 px = width / 20;
  
 if (currentLetters.length == 11) {
  clearInterval(newIntervalKey);
  c.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  c.font = 'bold italic ' + px + 'px Verdana';
    c.globalAlpha = 1;
    c.fillStyle = 'Red';
  c.fillText('GAME OVER', (width / 2 - width / 5.5), height / 2);
    
    c.font = 'bold italic' + px/2 + 'px Verdana'
    c.fillStyle = 'Black'
    c.globalAlpha = 0.1;
    c.fillText('Final Score:' + ' ' + score, (width / 2), (height / 2 + height / 10));
 }  
}

function where() {
  x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (width - width / 20));
  y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (height - width / 20)); 
    
  addRandomLetter();
  drawletters();
  letternumber += 1;
  stop();
}

function drawletters() {
  c.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  c.font = 'bold italic ' + px + 'px Verdana';
  c.globalAlpha = 1;
  c.fillStyle = 'Black';
  
  // This will loop through the array of our current letters and draw them
  // each on the specified coordinates. We get all that info from the objects
  // that we've stored in the array.
  currentLetters.forEach(function(char) {
    c.fillText(char.l, char.x, char.y);
  });
  
  c.font = 'bold italic ' + height / 1.5 + 'px Verdana';
  c.globalAlpha = 0.1;
  c.fillText(score, width / 3, height / 1.5);
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 2px solid blue; }
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Canvas</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas></canvas>
    <input type="button" value="Start" id="startButton" />
    <input type="button" value="Stop" id="stopButton" />
  </body>
</html>
```

I need to somehow export all of the code and make it work on Brackets (my programming software)

I tried to make an index.html and a script.js file and then paste the html and JS code from jsfiddle there. But then when i try to run the index.html, my entire canvas is gone. I know it has something to do with the CSS part of jsfiddle, i just need help to incorperate it to my index.html file so that i can run the entire program from index.html

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `<style>` tag in your html's `<head>` tag and specify the css within that tag.

Comment: For the record, you can initialize `letter` much easier using something like `[...Array(26).keys()].map(i => String.fromCharCode(i + 0x41))`

Answer (score 2):

This really has nothing to do with JS Fiddle, per se. It's just a matter of how HTML, CSS and JavaScript are meant to be organized. It can be put together in several ways, but the most basic is to have it all in one file and have that file broken up into different sections. See the combined code below. You can just copy all of it and save it to your `index.html` file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Canvas</title>
    
    <!-- CSS can be embedded into an HTML file by placing it inside
         of HTML <style> </style> tags that are placed in the <head>
         section of the document. -->
    <style>
      canvas { border: 2px solid blue; }
      body { margin: 0; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas></canvas>
    <input type="button" value="Start" id="startButton" />
    <input type="button" value="Stop" id="stopButton" />
    
    <!-- JavaScript can be embedded into an HTML document by placing 
         it inside of <script> </script> tags and those tags can be
         placed in the <head>, <body> or both, but by placing your
         <script> just before the closing <body> tag, it ensures that
         the script won't run until all of the HTML has been parsed
         into memory. -->
    <script>
      var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
      var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

      var height = window.innerHeight;
      var width = window.innerWidth;

      canvas.width = width;
      canvas.height = height;

      var letter = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];

      var currentLetters = [];

      var px = height / 20;
      var y = [];
      var x = [];
      var speed;
      var acceleration;
      var score;
      var newIntervalKey = 0;
      var letternumber = 0;
      var score = 0;

      // This part will detect the clicks of your buttons. It's the preferred method for
      // handling events in JS as opposed to using the onClick attribute of HTML elements.

      var startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');
      startButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
       start();
      }, false);

      var stopButton = document.getElementById('stopButton');
      stopButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
       stop();
      }, false);

      // This will get the key code of the keyboard key that the user pressed.
      // Each letter corresponds to such a code, so that's how you can check
      // if the user pressed the correct key. Obviously you will need to have
      // some soft of a map of codes to letters.
      document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {

        // Getting a letter from a code. We have a function that does that.
        var currentlyPressedKey = getKeyFromCode(e.keyCode);
  
        // If the user pressed one of the letters currently in play, we
        // remove it from our currentLetters array. We are using a bad
        // way of doing it (using a for loop) because I don't know if
        // you have covered array methods yet.
        for (var i = 0; i < currentLetters.length; i++) {
         var letterObj = currentLetters[i];
          if (letterObj.l == currentlyPressedKey) {
           currentLetters.splice(i, 1);
            score += 1;
          }
        }
      }, false);

      function getKeyFromCode(code) {
       switch (code) {
         case 65:
           return 'A';
          case 66:
           return 'B';
          case 67:
           return 'C';
          case 68:
           return 'D';
          case 69:
           return 'E';
          case 70:
           return 'F';
          case 71:
           return 'G';
          case 72:
           return 'H';
          case 73:
           return 'I';
          case 74:
           return 'J';
          case 75:
           return 'K';
          case 76:
           return 'L'
          case 77:
           return 'M';
          case 78:
           return 'N';
          case 79:
           return 'O';
          case 80:
           return 'P';
          case 81:
           return 'Q';
          case 82:
           return 'R';
          case 83:
           return 'S'
          case 84:
           return 'T';
          case 85:
           return 'U';
          case 86:
           return 'V';
          case 87:
           return 'W'
          case 88:
           return 'X';
          case 89:
           return 'Y';
          case 90:
           return 'Z';
          //case 50:
          // return 'W';
    
          default:
           //return null;  <-- this makes no sense
            break;
        }
      }

      function addRandomLetter() {
       var letternumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26);
  
        // This will pick the x and y coordinated for each letter. It will need to be
        // updated later, because right now it's technically possible to place a
        // letter all the way on the bottom or on the right, where the user won't be
        // able to see it.
        var positionX = Math.floor(Math.random() * width);
        var positionY = Math.floor(Math.random() * height);
  
        // This saves an object to our array of current letters. The object contains
        // the letter itself, but also its x and y coordinates that we generated above.
       currentLetters.push({l: letter[letternumber], x: positionX, y: positionY});
      }

      function start() {

       c.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
       letternumber = 0;
        currentLetters = []
        score = 0;
  
       if(newIntervalKey != 0) {
        clearInterval(newIntervalKey)
       }
  
       newIntervalKey = setInterval(where, 1000);
      }

      function stop() {
       px = width / 20;
  
       if (currentLetters.length == 11) {
        clearInterval(newIntervalKey);
        c.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        c.font = 'bold italic ' + px + 'px Verdana';
          c.globalAlpha = 1;
          c.fillStyle = 'Red';
        c.fillText('GAME OVER', (width / 2 - width / 5.5), height / 2);
    
          c.font = 'bold italic' + px/2 + 'px Verdana'
          c.fillStyle = 'Black'
          c.globalAlpha = 0.1;
          c.fillText('Final Score:' + ' ' + score, (width / 2), (height / 2 + height / 10));
       }  
      }

      function where() {
        x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (width - width / 20));
        y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (height - width / 20)); 
    
        addRandomLetter();
        drawletters();
        letternumber += 1;
        stop();
      }

      function drawletters() {
        c.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        c.font = 'bold italic ' + px + 'px Verdana';
        c.globalAlpha = 1;
        c.fillStyle = 'Black';
  
        // This will loop through the array of our current letters and draw them
        // each on the specified coordinates. We get all that info from the objects
        // that we've stored in the array.
        currentLetters.forEach(function(char) {
          c.fillText(char.l, char.x, char.y);
        });
  
        c.font = 'bold italic ' + height / 1.5 + 'px Verdana';
        c.globalAlpha = 0.1;
        c.fillText(score, width / 3, height / 1.5);
      }
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```